# iTerm2 Shell Integration and Oh My Zsh Conflicts

Tags: shell, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I've recently re-installed iTerm2 and am now running into an interesting problem after setting up iTerm's Shell Integration.

Upon open a new terminal window, everything seems to look correct, showing the proper "agnoster" theme from Oh My ZSH:

[image: working]

If I issue `clear`, now my terminal window looks like this:

[image: not working]

I can revert things to the original state by sourcing `~/.zshrc` once again, but I'm really curious about the root issue and if there's any way to fix it.

I have tried hiding the marker in iTerm's settings, but that just results in a blank terminal.

In a previous install (before I wiped this Mac), I had Oh My ZSH and Shell Integration both going, and although it looked kind of wonky at times, it still seemed to keep the Oh My ZSH theme regardless of clearing the terminal or issuing any other command.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I've checked the iTerm settings over and over, but can't seem to find anything that would be related.

Comment: There is an issue on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/4327). Maybe it can help you.

Comment: @NaN - Thanks, this looks to be the problem! I was able to use the solution below and now things are working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just installed the Shell Integration in iTerm 2 (Build 2.9.20160313) and had the exact same problem.

The way I solved it was by adding a single line to  `~/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh` right after `export ITERM_SHELL_INTEGRATION_INSTALLED=Yes` at line 3:

`ITERM2_PRECMD_PS1="$PS1"`

Thus, this is how the head of the above-mentioned file looks:

```
if [[ -o login ]]; then
  if [ "$TERM" != "screen" -a "$ITERM_SHELL_INTEGRATION_INSTALLED" = "" ]; then
    export ITERM_SHELL_INTEGRATION_INSTALLED=Yes

    ## BEGIN EDIT
    ITERM2_PRECMD_PS1="$PS1"
    ## END EDIT

    # Indicates start of command output. Runs just before command executes.
    iterm2_before_cmd_executes() {
      printf "\033]133;C;\007"
    }

    # ...
```

It's likely a bug, since (as you can see from the comments in the same file) the script is supposed to save your `$PS1` on login, but it does not.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you for the quick response. Now I can get to work! :)

Comment: I also comment line 4: `ITERM2_SHOULD_DECORATE_PROMPT="1"`

Answer (score 16):

Late answer but this worked for me.

The iTerm2 Shell Integrations page has you download the install script and pipe it into bash.

**Instead**, download it locally and modify it so it knows you are using ZSH.

First, download the script

```
wget https://iterm2.com/misc/install_shell_integration.sh
```

Then, instead of having the script determine the shell just define it as "zsh"

```
# comment out this line
# SHELL=$(echo "${SHELL}" | tr / "\n" | tail -1)

# replace it with this line
SHELL="zsh"
```

Next, make the install script executable and then run it

```
chmod +x install_shell_integration.sh
./install_shell_integration.sh
```

After that the integration should be installed properly.

**Note** 
Remove the Bash integration if you don't need it.

```
rm ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. The problem was: even though I was using zsh for some reason by SHELL variable was bash! hardcoding it to zsh did the trick!

Comment: This is no longer necessary since the bug has been fixed. Anyway it stills shows how to install the integration.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still having this issue, there's now an option in iterm's profile settings that allows you to disable these "marks" ( which are detailed under the "marks" section [on this page](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) )

1. Open iterm preferences
2. Select "profiles"
3. Select the profile
4. Select "Terminal" tab
5. Untick the "Shell Integration > Show mark indicators" checkbox

[Screenshot of the setting within iterm preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeXXh.png)